# Cross Browser PNG masking of page Background

Tags: css, webkit, png, mask

I have implemented a mask successfully for my web page that runs the full length of the page in Chrome, however does not work in Firefox or IE. Any suggestions. Tried SVG route however, does not work

Code

```
<div class="mask-bg bg-blue"> Entire Site Here</div>
```

Style

```
display: block;
width: 100%;
mask: url(mask.png);
-webkit-mask-image: url(mask.png);
mask-image: url(mask.png);
-webkit-mask-position: top center;
mask-position: top center;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-y;
mask-repeat: repeat-y;
mask-size: cover;
-webkit-mask-size:cover;
```

Comment: Looks like masks are very poorly supported at this time: [http://caniuse.com/css-masks](http://caniuse.com/css-masks)

Comment: I know, unfortunately, its a design requirement for the website so need to try find a fix